# Mockk: how to do assertEquals with using "any Class" as a field value of the expected object?

Tags: kotlin, junit, mockk

I'm trying to write a JUnit 5 test in Kotlin using Mockk. Assuming I have the following code that I want to test (it's a simplified example):

```kotlin
class AccountFactory {
    fun createAccount(): Account {
        return Account(
            id = 1,
            createdAt = Timestamp.from(Instant.now())
        )
    }
}
```

and my test looks like this:

```kotlin
    @Test
    fun createAccount() {
        val actual = accountFactory.createAccount()
        val expected = Account(id = 1, createdAt = ???)
        assertEquals(expected, actual)
    }
```

So I cannot figure out, how can I assign "any Timestamp" to `createdAt` field of the `expected` object? Checked Mockk docs, there are some examples using `any()` but only for mocked method arguments. Is it even possible to use something like this for assertions? If no, what is the better way of verifying the actual object other than checking every field value separately (which is not ideal in case new fields are added to Account later)?

Answer (score 1):

You can divide the assertion into multiple ones as follows:

1. You check that the id is the same `assertEquals(1, actual.getId())`
2. You check that the Timestamp is not null `assertNotNull(actual.getCreatedAt())`
3. You check that the Timespamp belongs to the right class `assertEquals(Timestamp.class, actual.getCreatedAt().class)`

The above is the idea in pseudo-code as I do not know Kotlin. Anyway, the theory holds. You can't assert the two objects to be equals because of the timestamp, therefore you first check the constant value(s), then you make sure the timestamp is not Null and it is actually of the intended class. Furthermore, you might decide to assert the date from the timestamp is the same, though I would recommend you not to.

Cheers,

D

Comment: the problem is that this way (checking each field separately) I will have to update the test every time a new field is added to Account class (or have the test not checking some newly-added fields, which is probably not what I want to do). So checking the whole object against an expected object is kinda more strict and safer. The only problem is how to construct the expected object the way some fields will match ANY value of the same type from the actual object